Identify this action movie about some young billionaire criminal who do extreme sports
I have watched a movie trailer a few months ago. It was about a police officer who try to infiltrate a group of billionaires who do extreme sports and in their spare time they rob banks. 
The scenes I remember from the trailer

There is a part where they jump out from a plane with a pallet of money over a (rain)forest.
There is a scene about a big party on a boat
There is a part where they are surfing and the police guy almost drown, but the main bad guy saves his life

The movie release date should be between 2014-2018 so it's a new movie. It looked like an american production with high budget. 

How did I miss this?

Sounds like the Point Break remake from 2015 [which some people would rather forget ;)].

A young FBI agent infiltrates an extraordinary team of extreme sports athletes he suspects of masterminding a string of unprecedented, sophisticated corporate heists. 

Here's the trailer, which features some of the scenes you've mentioned:



